# How to send command in separate python window

Tags: python

Searching isn't pulling up anything useful so perhaps my verbiage is wrong.

I have a python application that I didn't write that takes user input and performs tasks based on the input. The other script I did write watches the serial traffic for a specific match condition. Both scripts run in different windows. What I want to do is if I get a match condition from my script output a command to the other script. Is there a way to do this with python? I am working in windows and want to send the output to a different window.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can start the script within your script, you can just follow the instructions in this link: [Read from the terminal in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361763/read-from-the-terminal-in-python)

old answer:
*I assume you can modify the code in the application you didn't write.* If so, you can tell the code to "print" what it's putting on the window to a file, and your other code could constantly monitor that file.

Comment: That is an interesting thought I'll look into it more though I'm not sure I have much control over the code I didn't write and it's constantly being developed. I could however start the script from within my script if that would help bring any new ideas to the table.